# Can we change android tv search results display priority?

Tags: android, android-tv

Scenario:
pm come up a new requirement,in google luncher we can search content(e.g. Big Buck Bunny),and luncher will display all the results include our own apk`s result,we want set our apk`s reslut in the top,usually the result of the top line is YouTube`s result.Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can make your apk searchable, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions for how to do so.  But you don't get control over how google ranks things.